# CSS div gap between elements

Tags: html, css

I found too many references about this subject already answered, but I didn't found one satisfactory answered.

Follow de case:

[image]

I have created a minimalist fiddle with expected behavior:

[image]

@ [See fidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/C5JEE/)

If a have 3 cels I wish spacer only between each div. This is possible using only CSS?

**[HTML]**

```
<div class="cel-1-2">
   Max Size of Objects in Cache (Shared Memory)
    <div class="cel-1-2">
        <input type="text" placeholder="foo" />
    </div>
    <div class="cel-1-2">
        <select>
            <option value="foo">bar</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="cel-1-2">
    foobar
</div>
```

**[CSS]**

```
[class*=cel-] {
   padding-right:10px;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;     
   box-sizing: border-box;
    background: blue;
}

.cel-1-2 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

input, select {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Been more clear:

### This is what I want

[image]

### ==>NOT this!

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use margin-left on select wrapper?

Comment: Whatever, I just want spacing between divs - can be margin, padding ... Whatever works :)

Comment: @Ragen Dazs : I hope this will help you..http://jsfiddle.net/pragneshkaria/C5JEE/8/

Comment: Thanks @PragneshKaria, but this not solves the problem - I have edited the post with two images with expected behavior. If I put 4px in margin-left my layout will be misaligned

Comment: @RagenDazs : Little confusion about , three boxes. In image you have three boxes , inside "<div class="cel-1-2">". But actually as per the HTML you have provided, "<div class="cel-1-2">" is divided in to input and selectbox , and both width is approx 50%. Can you please be more clear?

Comment: Are your elements inline or inline-block ? It could explain the gap (white space wrapping them).

Comment: @enguerranws what I want to do is exactly the spacing between the DIVs as showing the last two images

Comment: Ok, I answered with an example to reproduce what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is the issue here. **That can be easily done with CSS** :

```
.parent {
   width: 100%;
   background: green;
    padding: 1em 0; 
    height: 500px;
}
.child {
    width: 30%;
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
    float: left;
}
.child + .child {
    margin-left: 5% /* 1 000 000 $ TIP */
}
```

Live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hDqbk/

Comment: Yeees man! Thanks for your $ 1 million tip!!!!! I think it must be  $ 1 billion :)

Comment: Can you explain what `.child + .child` does?

Comment: It targets every .child that has a .child right before. For example : <div class="child"></div><div class="child"></div> will target only the second one. Basically, it's a CSS2 equivalent to CSS3 :nth-child(n+1).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set a margin-left to all child and then reset the first.
http://jsfiddle.net/r66BG/3/

```
.child {    
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.child:first-child {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Great Marinho San, after all with http://jsfiddle.net/hDqbk/3/ I can use without problems!

Answer (score 0):

I am new to web design but If I did not get your question wrong I can recommend these:
1) Use bootstrap to place those divs on the same line, bootstrap will create the spacing automatically.

2) Manually moving divs using margin property which I don't recommend

P.S.: I was going to comment to ask for a little bit clarification but I do not have enough rep yet. If this is irrelevant please ignore and I will try to come up with a relevant answer

Comment: Downvote.  You don't need to implement an entire front-end framework to fix some CSS spacing issues.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use twitter bootstrap to build your site. It is simple, it is strong, it is responsive. I tried to use it to your code like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Student Program Management</title>
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <p>Max Size of Objects in Cache (Shared Memory)</p>
                <div class="col-md-4 ">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="foo" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select>
                        <option value="foo">bar</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    foobar
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But yes, there is also other ways to use simple css, but in many cases it is much more painful then this approach. Bootstrap is based on **Grid Layout system**, where your site is decided to as many rows **(attribute class = "row" in div element)** as you wish. Then inside a row, you can put columns (div with attribudte class="col-md-4" - for example). One row has 12 columns, so in my case, there are 3 rows in one column, so every div has class="col-md-4" becouse 12/3=4. Every div has now same width. I am not sure, if this is exactly what you want, but aim to frameworks like bootstrap is much more effective then use simple CSS, so I can only recommend you to ged rid of plain CSS if it is possible. You can find more here:  http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Bootstrap is a good solution for a few projects. You actually don't need your user to load 200ko of CSS to make columns or responsive website. It's way to heavy for most of websites actually.

Answer (score 0):

give the middle div a new class, and give that class the right properties.

for example:

```
.TheFloatingDiv{
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Hope this is the answer to your question, as i didn't understand it completely.